# Data from Redux Store doesn't reset after change Screen Component

Tags: react-native, redux

I have a problem with reset redux store data. I have Register component when I click signup button then I get errors and record them in store, then I draw under the inputs.

[image]

Now, if I back to Login screen and then go back again to Register screen the errors still shown but I don't want to see them.

**How I can solve this problem?** I understand that I need to set initial state every time when I go to a screen. I tried to set initial state to createStore but it doesn't work. Also I use Redux Observable's Epics.

Comment: Just dispatch an action to update your redux state, the same way you did to set errors. You can do this when user goes back, or he changes his inputs...

Comment: I can create another one action like SET_INIT_STATE and use it every time when I need to set initial state using it in lifecycle right?

Comment: Sure, you can do it

Comment: @Milore It works perfect! Thx